# React API mapping issue

Tags: reactjs, mapping, fetch

I'm trying to make a simple fetch request and trying to map through the response to display on the page.

The API results correctly display when I console.log(data) but once I add the mapping function they display as undefined. I have tried both data.map and data.results.map

I couldn't find a working solution in any other thread!

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://private-cc77e-aff.apiary-mock.com/posts")
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => {
          let posts = data.results.map(post => {
          console.log(posts);
          });
      });
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: your map function doesn't return anything

Comment: what do you want to achieve using map ? it is unclear what you are doing with map there

Comment: @aravind_reddy where the console.log is I want to display each of the posts in an <li> but I can't even get them to display in the console. Am I missing something?

Comment: you are trying to log `posts` before you finish populating the variable (`.map` wasn't done yet).

Comment: @Sagivb.g ok thanks - what would I add to do that?

Comment: yes then you are trying to console.log it before completion of map itself. do it like this `let posts = data.results.map(post =>  post); console.log(posts)`  see if it is working this way

Comment: are you just trying to display fetched data? just store it in state and render it. if you need an example i'll post it as an answer

Comment: thanks @aravind_reddy - its still showing as Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in the console?

Comment: @Sagivb.g if you could that would be amazing, this is my first time with APIs!

Comment: so first try console logging data then

Comment: yeah storing it in state and rendering it is the best method

Comment: @LauraAnnabel89 hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is the structure of your data but part of your problem is that you are trying to log `posts` before `.map` has finish populating it.

What you could do is storing the data received from the API in state (use `map` if you need to normalize the data) and then in render reference it using `this.state.posts`.

Don't forget to start with an initial value of an empty array, and you can conditionally render the posts or a loader based on the length of the array.

Here is a small example with code similar to your use case:

```js
const Joke = ({joke}) => <div style={{border: '1px solid #ccc', padding: '15px'}}>{joke}</div>

class App extends React.Component {
  // initial value (array)
  state = { jokes: [] }

  componentDidMount() {
    // get data when component monuted 
    fetch("https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/10")
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(result => {
      // normalize data with map
      const jokes = result.value.map(obj => obj.joke);
      // update the state for next render
      this.setState({jokes})
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { jokes } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {
          // conditionally render the array or loading (if data isn;t ready yet)
          jokes.length
            ? jokes.map(joke => <Joke joke={joke} />)
            : "Loading..."
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: @LauraAnnabel89 glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

We are not quite sure how is your API response but you are doing the log operation somehow wrong. You are assigning the `posts` to a variable, but you re trying to use it inside the `.map` method.

I assume that your API response is something like that:

```
{
  results: [
    { id: 1, name: "foo" },
    { id: 2, name: "bar" },
    { id: 3, name: "baz" },
  ],
};
```

This is data and since you are assigning `data.results` as posts this is why I assume a response like that. I'm providing the options you can try. Here, I am mimicking the API request with a function, so do not bother with this part, please.

**Just log the whole `results` array.**

```js
const data = {
  results: [
    { id: 1, name: "foo" },
    { id: 2, name: "bar" },
    { id: 3, name: "baz" },
  ],
};

const fakeRequest = () =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(data), 1000));

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    fakeRequest()
      .then( data => {
        console.log( data.results );
      })
  }
  render() {
    return <div>Look the console. We are logging the whole array.</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**You can map the array and log each item one by one**

Since we just want to log the items, we don't need to use `map` here, `forEach` is enough.

```js
const data = {
  results: [
    { id: 1, name: "foo" },
    { id: 2, name: "bar" },
    { id: 3, name: "baz" },
  ],
};

const fakeRequest = () =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(data), 1000));

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    fakeRequest()
      .then( data => {
        data.results.forEach( post => console.log( post) )
        // or as a shorthand
        // data.results.forEach(console.log)
      })
  }
  render() {
    return <div>Look the console. We are logging each post one by one.</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Set your state with the results and map it in your render method**

This is most of the time you want to do. Just logging is not enough as we know.

```js
const data = {
  results: [
    { id: 1, name: "foo" },
    { id: 2, name: "bar" },
    { id: 3, name: "baz" },
  ],
};

const fakeRequest = () =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(data), 1000));

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    posts: [],
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fakeRequest()
      .then( data => {
        this.setState( { posts: data.results})
      })
  }
  render() {
    if ( !this.state.posts.length ) {
      return <p>No posts yet</p>
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.posts.map( post =>
            <div key={post.id}>
            <p>{post.id}</p>
            <p>{post.name}</p>
            </div>
          )
        }
      </div>
      );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```